# Unable to see project even as GCP owner

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am the owner of an organization and have a project I can see as another secondary user but not as the owner of the organization

I see both users listed in IAM with both showing "owner" of the project

But in the project selector, it is not present

any ideaS?

Comment: Do you have such issue only with one project? Have you tried to ask another user to remove your `owner` role and then grant it back to you? Are you facing this issue in different browsers? Are you able to connect to this project with `gcloud` commands?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an issue on Google's side.

**To solve this issue** you should report it to [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub#section-2) or file an [issue report](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports) at [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).